# How to fetch details of item, when user opens details page directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I was going through official Redux tutorial ([Redux Essential](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data)) and I believe there is one thing missing. There is a simple "List/Details" example and it's all clear, but the Details page (`SinglePostPage`) will not work, if user types the exact address in the address bar manually. In other words, if you open the website directly on the SinglePostPage - the list of posts will not be fetched, thus Page will display: **Post not found!**. The only way to view the post, is to open the list first, then click "View Post".

Here is a `SinglePostPage`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const SinglePostPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { postId } = match.params

  const post = useSelector(state =>
    state.posts.find(post => post.id === postId)
  )

  if (!post) {
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Post not found!</h2>
      </section>
    )
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <article className="post">
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
        <p className="post-content">{post.content}</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  )
}
```

I could simply fetch this post, like it's done for posts, but my biggest concern is, that in the first render useSelector will return undefined post, before it will dispatch fetch action. How will I know if "undefined" means that post was not found or if it wasn't even fetched?

So my question is, what's the best way to handle it? Should I create a separate slice for single post with loading status and error? Similar to `postsSlice`? I'm not sure If I should have two slices per one feature. Should I?

*EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not saying that tutorial has a bug. It's a very simple, not-real-life-app sample. The fact that you can't open post's details by typing direct URL in the browser was not covered by the tutorial. So my question is about possible solution to this "issue".*

Comment: If you really believe there is something missing, that's a documentation bug you should probably file over on the redux issue tracker, in addition to keeping this question here for folks to answer. If the tutorial is missing information you are not going to be the only one who runs into that, and having the folks who curate the tutorials fix that will benefit far more people than just you getting an answer here.

Comment: In the documentation: `It's possible that we might not have a matching post entry in the store - maybe the user tried to type in the URL directly, or we don't have the right data loaded. If that happens, the find() function will return undefined instead of an actual post object. Our component needs to check for that and handle it by showing a "Post not found!" message in the page.` If you don't want this behavior then fetch the single post in an action and save the states (loading error) of a single post. I agree that the documentation is not good as it over simplifies fetching data.

Comment: @HMR I'm debating with myself if I should create a separate slice only for a selected post or should I add "selected" object with post itself, states and loading error inside the posts slice?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans unfortunately it's not a bug. The simplified version was done on purpose with no plans turning it the real-world-application (I think). Do you have any suggestion how to handle it, specially in the store?

Comment: Issues are not bugs. Issues _can_ be bugs, but they can also be requests to make documentation more explicit because it's not clear enough for folks. If the tutorial covers what it should cover and you're just trying to do something that isn't in the tutorial, then you should probably update your post text, but if you are purely following the tutorial and it feels like something is missing, that's a documentation issue that you should raise with the redux folks.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, I never mentioned that it's an "issue" or a "bug". I raised that question in their discord already, and it's not in scope of the tutorial. When I said "something is missing" I mean it's missing for me - I described exactly what tutorial is missing and asked for help/advice how to implement it. In any event, I updated my question.